# Fatal error: Selenium is looking for firefox, how do I install it

Tags: selenium

I have access to my server through **SSH** and I am trying to get selenium facebook webdriver working and after installing java and selenium at this line:

```
$host = 'http://localhost:4444/wd/hub'; 
$capabilities = DesiredCapabilities::firefox();
$driver = RemoteWebDriver::create($host, $capabilities, 5000);
```

I got to this error:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Facebook\WebDriver\Exception\UnknownServerException' 
with message 'Cannot find firefox binary in PATH. Make sure firefox is       
installed. OS appears to be: LINUX Build info: version: '2.53.1', revision: 'a36b8b1',....
```

Do I need to install firefox? how?  bear in mind that I have SSH access and as per error the system is linux. Maybe it is something with the path.

Comment: if you want to run tests with firefox, you must have firefox installed

Comment: AFAIK `Firefox` is default browser for `Linux`.. You don't know whether it installed or not?

Comment: Andersson: No. How do I find out whether it is installed or not?

Comment: @Andersson Firefox is not installed on most linux servers.. neither is X11

Comment: @user7432810 after you get Firefox and X11 installed, you will need to use Xvfb since there is most likely no physical display attached to the remote server.

Answer (score 0):

Linux servers with no GUI environments don't come with Firefox, to install you can do `sudo apt-get install firefox` but I doubt it will work since it doesn't have a graphical environment.

I urge you to use [PhantomJS](http://phantomjs.org/) as an alternative.

Comment: It will indeed work because `sudo apt-get install firefox` will pull in all dependencies, including the X11 server.

Comment: using PhantomJS is not helpful if you want a real browser

Comment: the OP will also need to use Xvfb to run headless.